# Installing COIN-OR for PuLP

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, pulp, coin-or

I have solved simple MILP problems with PuLP and I believe ‘model.solve()’ without any parameters refers to the default solver.
But for harder problems, it keeps running and and I can’t get a result.
I’m wondering how I can install and add free solvers (i.e. not CPLEX or Gurobi) as a solver. I found COIN-OR but I couldn’t find the right structure and documentation to use it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Regards,
Behrouz

Comment: The default solver is an older version of COIN-OR so you may not get much improvement

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the solver. This will depend on solver and your operating system, but should be fairly googleable.
2. Check its installed and pulp can access it by running:

   `import pulp`

   `pulp.pulpTestAll()`

This will try all solvers and confirm which available.

3. Solve your model using `model.solve(solver)`. For example `model.solve(pulp.COIN_CMD())`

More here: https://scaron.info/blog/linear-programming-in-python-with-pulp.html

Comment: Thank you @kabdulla. I was having issue with installing the solver as each one of them seems to have their own procedure. I managed to install Gurobi. Thanks again.